# using "general" instead of "brigadier general"

Tags: military

Suppose Mr. Parker is a brigadier general in the army. could we simply refer to him as "General Parker". In other words, can "General" be used as a generic title for anyone with a high rank in the army?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*General* can be used as a generic title for anyone in the Army of rank O-7 or above. In the cases of 1-, 2-, and 3-star generals, their formal titles are Brigadier, Major, and Lieutenant General, but just plain *General* can be used, particularly verbally. "We need to clean up around here; General Parker is paying us a visit this afternoon" is a legitimate way to refer to the 1-star. In writing, shorthand is often used to prevent ambiguity, so the same remark in an email might read:

> We need to clean up around here; BGen Parker is paying us a visit this afternoon.

When saluting BGen Parker in the parking lot, "Good morning, General" would be an appropriate verbal greeting – assuming the local time hasn't passed 1200 hrs.

From a [Marine Corps customs and courtesies guide](http://www.usnavy.vt.edu/Marines/PLC_Junior/Fall_Semester/GMK1010_Customs&Courtesies%20SO.pdf) (p. 9):

> *In written correspondence, both formal and social, full rank precedes the name and is written out. In conversation, all generals are General*...

Comment: _General_ is in fact short for _general officer_, and that phrase gets used in certain formal situations in the American military. But _general_ is now a noun as well as an adjective.

Comment: Is it Marine Corps regulation to say "Good afternoon" after 1200 hours?

Comment: @Press  - No, but it's regulation to give a respectful greeting.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say *which* army, and in the British Army things are slightly different from the rules J.R. gives for the US Army. The NATO equivalent to US Army O-7 is OF-6, one-star general; the British Army equivalent to this rank is Brigadier, and

> While the corresponding rank of brigadier general in many other
>   nations is a general officer rank, the British Army considers it a
>   field officer rank.

([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigadier_%28United_Kingdom%29))

Perhaps as a consequence, British Army brigadiers are addressed *not* as 'General', but as 'Brigadier':

> How to Address a Brigadier
>
> The recommended social style of address is as follows:
>
> Verbal communication:     Brigadier Jones*
>
> *A younger man, or a more junior officer in any of the Armed Forces, addresses him as 'Sir'.

([Debrett's](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/professions/armed-forces/army/brigadier))

You have to be a Major General or above to get addressed as General ([Debrett's](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/professions/armed-forces/army/general-lieutenant-general-and-major-general) again)

So the answer to your question depends on which army Mr Parker is in.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S. Army (50 years ago, anyway, when I was a service member), a general officer was so called because he could be assigned to command Army forces of any type; hence, generals' uniforms did not indicate a corps affiliation (Engineers, Signal, etc.). "Generalist" was the idea.

Comment: You need a source for this answer. Personal anecdotes are usually not enough.